# Can I trust Azure Blob RetryPolicy? Why I cannot find these retry requests in fiddler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, retrypolicy

I tried to download a file from an empty blob container, and I got 404 as expected. The question is I see only 1 call for this file in fiddler, instead of 3 (as I specified in the RetryPolicy), also I notice the call finishes within 1 second, so it definitely did not wait for 10 seconds before try it again...
How do I know if the BlobClient really did the retry?

`var blobClient = this.storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 3);
var anchorString = await cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(ARGO_ANCHOR_VERSION_FILE).DownloadTextAsync();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is I see only 1 call for this file in fiddler, instead of
>   3 (as I specified in the RetryPolicy)

This is expected behavior as the default retry policies (Linear, Exponential etc.) don't retry all operations. **Retry policies are for handling `transient` errors**. You mentioned that you got 404 (Not Found) error and that is not a retryable operation as it is not a transient error. Usually errors with status code 500+ are retryable by default.

You can however create a custom retry policy and make any error code retryable. I wrote a blog post long time back on retry polcies and there I wrote some code for creating a custom retry policy. You can create a custom retry policy that treats 404 error as a tranient error and then you should see storage client library retrying your operation. You can read that post here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/12/30/storage-client-library-2-0-implementing-retry-policies/.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It is confusing as I saw the StorageException.IsRetryable = true for this exception though

Comment: Do take a look at the code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/StorageException.cs. Based on this `IsRetryable` is only set false in case of an `ArgumentException` (e.g. you provide an invalid blob container name). HTH.